Sci-fi short story I read in highschool around 30 years ago about a dying alien race
I may be getting the details slight wrong, but here we go:
It was a story about a dying alien race that had been either conquered or just slowly exterminated by humanity.  And the way that the remaining aliens survived was by masquerading as exceptionally good house-wives.  Basically being forced into human society.
The story was about one of these aliens who got sick of having to do this, and would go out when her "husband" was away at work, and she would relive her warrior life, sometimes killing things. While doing this she ran across another one of her species.   IIRC they eventually decided that it wasn't really possible to bring back their race.
It's definitely a commentary on society, and the role of women in society.  The title and author escapes me, and it's driving me up the wall.    Probably too vague/old for anyone to remember, but I figured it's worth taking a shot to see if anyone has a clue what I'm talking about.

Reminiscent of but not "The Misogynist" by James Gunn.
